# app.js:51471 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Navigation cancelled from "/customer/login" to "/customer/dashboard" with a new navigation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am using router push to redirect on other page after login but it is giving me this error

```
app.js:51471 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Navigation cancelled from "/customer/login" to "/customer/dashboard" with a new navigation.
```

from login page when customer logged in successfully I am pushing to next route like this

```
router.push(router.currentRoute.query.to || '/customer/dashboard')
```

I don't know where it goes wrong.

Here is route in router.js

```
if(!store.state.AppActiveUser.is_customer){
        if (!to.meta.authRequired && auth.isAuthenticated()) {
            router.push({ path: '/dashboard', name: 'dashboard', component: './views/DashboardAnalytics.vue' })
        }
    }else{
    if (!to.meta.authRequired && auth.isAuthenticated()) {
        router.push({ path: '/customer/dashboard', name: 'customer-dashboard', component: '@/views/apps/customerComponents/dashboard/DashboardAnalytics.vue' })
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to catch such errors with a `catch` branch to `router.push()`

```js
router.push({ 
  path: '/customer/dashboard', 
  name: 'customer-dashboard', 
  component: '@/views/apps/customerComponents/dashboard/DashboardAnalytics.vue' 
})
.catch(() => true);
```

Comment: Thanks it works for me. Can you please answer this question too?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65607985/app-js51471-uncaught-in-promise-error-navigation-cancelled-from-customer-l/65609662#65609662

Comment: Is not this the same question ?!

Comment: I'm running into a similar problem. While your suggestion works, do you have a link to any documentation that backs this up or at least points to this recommended fix?

Comment: @Nathan https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-failures.html#detecting-navigation-failures

Comment: Thank you. I found this on my own after some research, and I simply wrote a function to handle the error according to those docs. I appreciate you taking the time to comment though :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons this may happen is actually quite simple - the user clicked on a navigation item such as a button more than once before the route had changed. So the navigation to your second page is cancelled and replaced with a navigation to your second page again. This happened to me when I had directly hooked up a router push to a button like so (@click-event is a custom event emitted from the component):

```
@click-event="$router.push('/validate')"
```

If the user rage clicks on that button it will try to navigate more than once, causing the error. In my case the solution was to limit the event handler to just one trigger by using once.

```
@click-event.once="$router.push('/validate')"
```